is there any way i can get my money back? i paided more then 200 dollars on site named adurite
my payments got stuck in the memory pool for months after using adurite to buy roblox Limited's
is there any way i can fix this for the payment to go threw or can i use console commands to cancel the payment because it never got confirmed

A bitcoin payment that never got confirmed is a bitcoin payment that never happened. In which case you still have the money and should only need to instruct your wallet to forget the unconfirmed transaction
